# I have got too many sms from my php json sms api

Tags: php, json, api

I have tried PHP JSON request on my web site.
I use that for SMS sending purposes.
But I have got many SMS.

```
<?php
   // Your code here!
   // Takes raw data from the request
   $json = file_get_contents('URL');

   // Converts it into a PHP object
   $data = json_decode($json,true);
   print_r($data);
?>
```

Are there any other methods to do that instead of this method?

I want  to send SMS with my back end.

Comment: The code you show seems to be reading data and nothing to do with sending SMS messages.

Comment: I can't publish my code, But I used this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are other ways to make requests. Instead of using `file_get_contents` you could use [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle). Guzzle is the recommended way of making requests to other web services.